# Are delegates necessary here?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns

This might be very basic. But, I am not very sure if the delegates are necessary in the following scenario?
Are delegates used in synchronous ways? If yes, is it good to call a delegate method in a function called by a caller who is a delegate[Like the example below]?

```
class FooViewController: UIViewController {

    func login() {
       let loginHelper = LoginHelper()
       loginHelper.fooDelegate = self
       loginHelper.shouldEnableLogin()
    }

    func enableLogin() {
       // Do some UI updates
    }

    func reset() {
       // Clear some values in the views
    }
}

class LoginHelper {
    weak var delegate: fooDelegate?

    func shouldEnableLogin() {
       //clear some text views
        delegate.reset()
        //do some validation, synchronous
        delegate.enableLogin()
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends. Are you doing some background/data operation in shouldEnableLogin ? If not, it is not at all necessary else you are on right track.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are a design pattern that allows one object to send messages to another object when a specific event happens. Imagine an object A calls an object B to perform an action. Once the action is complete, object A should know that B has completed the task and take necessary action, this can be achieved with the help of delegates!

Answer (score -1):

I think the crux here is your question "Are delegates used in synchronous ways?".

The fundamental delegate mechanism is synchronous: I.e. the called delegate method will be on the same thread as the caller. So if the caller is your object then you control what thread this occurs on.

However the caller ***could*** create a new thread and then call the delegate method from that. So if the caller is not yours, check the documentation for it carefully before relying on the call being on the same thread.